# Can the unused section of the Sublime Text minimap be made transparent?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I love Sublime Text's minimap, but when I have multiple documents open side by side, it tends to take up valuable screen space, as you can see in the attached image (for those who don't know, the second image shows how the minimap cuts off any text below it, even when it's not displaying anything).

I don't want to hide the minimap completely, but I would love to be able to use the area of the minimap that's not showing anything. I guess making the background of the minimap completely transparent would work, but that would look horrible when the text in the minimap overlays the text in the document below, so it isn't optimal.

The best solution for me would be to have a non-transparent background in the minimap up until the last line of the document (in the minimap), and have a transparent background below that. Is something like that possible?

*PS. Sorry for the very tall image, it's the best way to get the issue across.*

[image]
[image]

Comment: This has to be feature request to be posted on https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues

Comment: I'm not sure if you're telling me that this doesn't belong here and should be a feature request, or if you're saying that this is a good idea which isn't in ST yet, and I should make it a feature request. If it's the first one: How am I supposed to know if this feature is in ST? I'm not asking this question just for laughs, I'm asking because I don't know. Also, I'm very curious as to why there are two votes to close this post.

Comment: Yes, I am telling this does not belong here because for this to work, Sublime Text has to implement it directly into its C++ source code, which is a proprietary code (closed source) and only Sublime Text developers have access to it. If you post this request on https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues, the Sublime Text development team will look into your request and decide whether it is worth to implement or not.

Comment: Like I _clearly_ said before: I'm _asking_ if this is possible. If it is not, say so, and suggest that I make it a feature request. Don't tell me that "this doesn't belong here", especially without giving me any context at all.

Comment: When I say **`This has to be feature request to be posted on github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues`** it means: 1) This is not possible for you to do it, unless you had access to Sublime Text source code; 2) It explicitly says it has to be a feature request. **`This has to be feature request to be posted on github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues`**  means it has to be a feature request; 3) I gave you the context, **`This has to be feature request to be posted on github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues`**, I did not said it should be a feature request, i.e., it has to be a feature request

Comment: Indeed, when I say **`This has to be feature request to be posted on github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues`** it is not 100% clear. But this is not an answer for your question. It is a simple comment to give you a hint, on your next step.

Comment: For clarity, no Sublime can't do this currently (except possibly as you stated by making the whole thing translucent, which is suboptimal at best). So indeed if you would like to see this happen you should submit an issue (which it looks like you already did).